# How to run multiple independent browsers in parallel with each having their own separate mouse cursor?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, bots, pyautogui

I want my program to simultanously perform various automated tasks in separate webbrowsers and more specifically: simulate mouse movement in each of them at the same time. I don't know how to achieve that.

I tried to find any solutions connected to virtualization, webbrowser extensions or possibilities of the pyautogui library alone - but couldn't really find anything.

Comment: It is not completely clear to me if you want to run the same mouse cursor movements in every browser at the same time or if you want to simulate different mouse cursor movements in multiple windows independent or each other.

Comment: I want to do the second thing. 

In each browser/window, I want to simulate different, independent mouse cursor movement according to my different tasks.

Comment: you just need one thread per driver/browser pair.

Comment: but it is possible to have only one mouse cursor for the entire windows system - and I want lots of mouse cursor running in parallel in the background for each browser - how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

This is a special case of "how can I get a leader program to
broadcast events to follower programs?"

Of the many ways to accomplish that,
[pub-sub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern)
is a convenient one.
The leader will send mouse events, which followers listen for
and replay in their individual Selenium sessions.

Pick a framework like Kafka or RabbitMQ.
Run N follower instances, each controlling a single Selenium browser driver.
Leader sends instructions on a single command channel,
or on N such channels if followers need individually tailored instructions.
Followers either locally log what happened in the browser,
or send reports of such observations to a channel the leader listens on.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and insights. 
As I’m new to programming, what you’ve written sounds to me a little bit like dark magic but it’s definitelly some anchor point. I will check much in-detail everything you have recommended there. 

Thank you!